# How to create "read only" version of the 'Sitecore Client Account Managing Role'?

Tags: sitecore-client

As per the title, I am trying to create a role which can read-only/view User Accounts - Similar to a "read only" version of the 'Sitecore Client Account Managing' role.

As far as I know there is currently no OOTB roles for such.

Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here the some steps to follow to achieve,

**1. Duplicate the Role:**

**Access Role Manager**: Log in to Sitecore and access the Role Manager.

**Duplicate the Role**: Locate the "Sitecore Client Account Managing" role and create a duplicate or clone of it.

**2. Modify Permissions:**

**Revoke Write Permissions:**

1. Review the permissions associated with the original role.
2. Revoke or limit the write permissions related to user management, such as creating, editing, or deleting users.

**Grant Read-Only Permissions:**

Ensure that the permissions related to viewing user accounts, details, and membership remain intact.
Configure permissions to allow viewing without granting write access.

**3. Test the Modified Role:**

**Assign Users/Groups:**

Assign test users or groups to the modified read-only role.

**Verify Access:**

Log in as a user assigned to the modified role and verify that they can view user accounts but cannot perform modifications.